# Underscore.js Find and return element in nested array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have data-structure like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "AAAA",
        "children": [
            {"name": "vvv", "id": 3},
            {"name": "vvv22", "id": 4}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "BBBB",
        "children": [
            {"name": "ggg", "id": 5},
            {"name": "ggggv22", "id": 6}
        ]
    },
]
```

And I want to find and return  child with given ID. How to achieve this using Underscore.js?

My current realisation without using Underscore:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     var dataItem= data[i];
     for (var j = 0; j < dataItem.children.length; j++) {
        var child = dataItem.children[j];
        if (child .id == id) {
             return child;  
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. [Pluck](https://underscorejs.org/#pluck) the `children` keys from your top level objects
2. [Flatten](https://underscorejs.org/#flatten) the resulting array
3. [Find the first object](https://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) matching the condition, e.g having the correct id
4. [Chain](https://underscorejs.org/#chain) these operations

which leads to

```
var res = _(data).chain().
    pluck('children').
    flatten().
    findWhere({id: 3}).
    value();
```

And a demo

```js
var data = [
    {
        "name": "AAAA",
        "children": [
            {"name": "vvv", "id": 3},
            {"name": "vvv22", "id": 4}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "BBBB",
        "children": [
            {"name": "ggg", "id": 5},
            {"name": "ggggv22", "id": 6}
        ]
    }
];
var res = _(data).chain().
    pluck('children').
    flatten().
    findWhere({id: 3}).
    value();
    
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Am I right that this example will only go 2 levels deep? I am looking for an example that can handle variable levels deep...

Comment: That's right. For a variable depth, you probably would use a recursion. Feel free to ask a question if you can't find what you want

Comment: I'm trying to use this by matching against an outside variable in the findWhere statement but it would appear the variable is not available to the methods. How would I handle this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I got this function using underscore which will do your work.

```
var getChild = function(id,data){
    var allChildren = _.flatten(_.pluck(data,'children'));
    var childWithId = _.find(allChildren,function(child){return child.id == id});
    return childWithId;
}

var child = getChild(5,data);
console.log(child);
```